# Sum of grouped by data in Pandas (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For my task, I need to understand some Python Pandas Code in order to make some modification and reimplement it using another programming language(Java).
I took some online tutorials, but still have issues with Pandas. For example, this lines:

```
uniq_page_df = df.groupby(["asin", "views_count"])
uniq_page_df = uniq_page_df.sum().reset_index()
sum_views_count = int(uniq_page_df["views_count"].sum())
```

In this part, as I understand, author tries to calculate total views count. So my question is, why do we need to group by and calculate sum for each group(line 2) and then calculate overall sum(line 3)? Why we cannot calculate it without grouping by? Or I didn’t understand this part of code correctly.

Another question is, why do we need to `reset_index()` after calculating `sum()` on line 2?

**UPDATE**: all columns in data frame are: asin, product_group, category_description, views_count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to make up some data as it's easier to describe what's happening.

This is what I think your code is attempting to do and a much simpler alternative:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 10, 5], [2, 20, 10], [1, 10, 15],
                   [3, 30, 20], [2, 20, 25], [1, 10, 30]],
                  columns=['asin', 'views_count', 'col'])

s = int(df.groupby(['asin', 'views_count']).sum().reset_index()['views_count'].sum())
# 60

t = df.drop_duplicates(['asin', 'views_count'])['views_count'].sum()
# 60
```

The first attempt is isolating data for unique `asin` & `view_count` combinations via a `groupby`. To query the required column again, `reset_index` is called. Then the subtotals are summed one final time. But you can do the same by dropping duplicates rows.

Comment: Sorry, I just updated 1 line of the code. Now its groped by 2 columns - asin and view_count

Comment: @HelloWorld, what are the other columns in your dataframe? it would help if you can paste `df.head().to_dict()` so we get an idea of your data.

Comment: Updated question with list of all columns

Comment: @HelloWorld, updated my answer, the logic should still be applicable with your data.

Answer (score 0):

To your first question, it looks like the author is calculating two different things here - you're correct in saying this is redundant. Simply running `df['views_count'].sum()` would return the same values as the final line.

For the second question, when you preform a `groupby().sum()`, pandas returns a dataframe with the index being the keys that were used in the group - in this case, the index values would be `asin` and `views_count`. `reset_index()` will recreate a default index starting at 0, so that `views_count` and `asin` can be accessed and treated like normal columns. A better way of doing this might be:

```
#To get total views:
sum_views_count = df['views_count'].sum()

#To get views by page:
unique_page_views = df.groupby(['asin', 'views_count']).sum()

#To get the original dataframe structure back
unique_page_views = unique_page_views.reset_index()
```

see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html and https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html for details.